# How to save sent messages in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

How to save the sent letter to the selected folder?
`Item.SaveSentMessageFolder` doesn't work.
There are no errors during debug

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)     
     Dim message As String
     Dim header As String
     Dim selectFolderName As String
     Dim selectFolderItem As Outlook.MAPIFolder
     Dim oOutlook As New Outlook.Application
     Dim MyData As DataObject
     Set MyData = New DataObject

     message = "Do you want to save the letter to a folder?"
     header = "Save"

     If MsgBox(message, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, header) = vbYes Then
         SavePopUp.Show
         MyData.GetFromClipboard

        selectFolderName = MyData.GetText(1)
         Set oNameSpace = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
         Set selectFolderItem = oNameSpace.Folders(1).Folders.Item("Projects").Folders.Item(selectFolderName)
         Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = selectFolderItem
     End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked that selectFolderItem  is not null? Hardcoding teh folder index (oNameSpace.Folders(1)) is a really bad idea.

Comment: Yes, I checked the specified path is valid

Comment: That is not what I asked - did you check at run-time (by placing a breakpoint) that the selectFolderItem variable is not null?

Comment: Yes, I checked. The folder specified is correct.

Answer (score 1):

*Is this what you are trying to do?*

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim Select_Folder As folder

    Dim message As String
        message = "Do you want to save the letter to a folder?"
    Dim header As String
        header = "Save"

    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" And Item.DeleteAfterSubmit = False Then

       If MsgBox(message, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, header) = vbYes Then
          'Display dialog box
          Set Select_Folder = Application.Session.PickFolder
          Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = Select_Folder
       End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But it still doesn’t save to the folder after sending the letter

Comment: No it`s my folders

Comment: I need to save not in the file system. Av folders created by me in outlook 
  https://prntscr.com/r8trm7

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not hardcode the store index (1). Access it by name.
Secondly, SaveSentMessageFolder  can only be set to a folder from the same store where the message is residing.